# NodeJS: Segmentation Fault

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

I've just installed Ubuntu 17 on a new machine then installed Nodejs and NPM. Now trying to do even a simple `node -v` and `npm -v` returns "Segmentation fault".

```
node -v --> Segmentation fault
npm -v --> Segmentation fault
$(which node) --> Segmentation fault
```

Tried to purge both Nodejs and NPM then reinstalled but same error.
Any ideas as to how to fix this?

Comment: What happens when you try `whereis node` or `locate node`

Comment: one idea- try again and use 'nvm' to install this time

Comment: What version of ubuntu did you install? 32 bit or 64 bit? Is node also of the same architecture?

Comment: I'm on a 64-bit machine. I believe apt-get can detect that. Not sure though.

Comment: This isn't an answer but I wouldn't use the repo version.  I've always kept mine in `$HOME/node` and added `$HOME/node/bin` to PATH.  Just hit https://nodejs.org and grab latest file, `tar xf node-...tar.xz;mv node-... node` and source or restart term